# Android 4.4 phonegap app seems sluggish

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, android-4.4-kitkat

i have a Android App built with Phonegap Build service and the app uses google maps the problem i have is that when i test in on Android 4.4 the map seems buggy when i pan around and use the zoom feature etc. I have tested in on earlier versions of Android 4.3 and the map is very smooth the zoom features are fluid.

Comment: One question are you testing on the real phone or the emulator?

Comment: i am testing on real devices

Comment: Does both devices i.e. Android 4.4 and Android 4.3 have the same hardware configuration?

Comment: yes they have the same configuration that i am aware of.

Comment: which version on phonegap are you using?

Comment: i am using version 3.7.0

Comment: You can try testing on another version of phonegap or also test it on another device with kitkat and see if the issue persists then report it.

Comment: i have downgraded and after further testing i have found that its not the google maps that is buggy but the whole app the web-kit is buggy everything, Just not sure why its like that when it works flawlessly on my android 4.3.

Answer (score 0):

It could be what your using to run the application.